# Loop text file using batch files

Tags: batch-file

I want loop through a flat file (text file) which has 3000 rows. I want to be able to print 30 rows, then print a note, then print the next 30 rows and a note again.

I have tried the below but it does not work.

```
For /L %%file in (1,30,3000) do echo %%file
```

Expect result:

> Name description description
>
> Xxxxx xxxxxxxxx   Xxxxxxx
>
> Xxxxx xxxxxxxxx   Xxxxxxx
>
> Some note to append
>
> Name description description
>
> Xxxxx xxxxxxxxx   Xxxxxxx
>
> Xxxxx xxxxxxxxx   Xxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is completely invalid. Metavariables need a single character and not a word. something like `%%i` but regardless, the `/L` loop will merely do something the number of times you tell it too, which will not do what you think here.. Try this:

**Note** Please ensure you change `D:\work dir\somefile.txt` in the 3rd line of the code, to your filename if in the same directory, else add full path to it if not.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=somefile.txt"
set /a cnt=0

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%file%) do (
 set /a "eval=(cnt+1)%%30"
 if not !eval! equ 0 echo %%i
 if !eval! equ 0 (
    echo %%i
    Echo Add YOUR note here!!!
)
 set /a cnt+=1
)
```

If you then require the note to be manually inserted by the user, use `set /p` like below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "file=somefile.txt"
set /a cnt=0

for /f "delims=" %%i in (%file%) do (
 set /a "eval=(cnt+1)%%30"
 if not !eval! equ 0 echo %%i
 if !eval! equ 0 (
    echo %%i
    set /p note=Add note?
    echo !note!
)
 set /a cnt+=1
)
```

Comment: result came out?

Comment: It i want it run show 30rows data and stop to add note on bottom and continue looping until end example 1,2,3,4,5 add note 6,7,8,9,10 add note 11,12,13,14,15 add note looping end of text file. I run it just now it loop but show every 30 rows

Comment: The two `set /a` can be combined in one `set /a "eval=(cnt+1)%%30,cnt+=1"` Only one IF neccessary when always echoing %%i first.

Comment: @LotPings yes thanks, added additional if due to requirements changes, so did not feel like changing and testing still. Will go through it and make the answer better. Thanks for the comment.